How do I correctly formulate the random effects with repeated measures in a paired design
Sorry if this is a cross-posting, but I haven't found the exact solution for my problem yet.
Let us assume I have an experiment with 20 households, with 2 people each (1 female + 1 male).
Over the course of 30 years I measure the same variable on each of these persons, but depending on the household, the number of measurements may differ and also the year when the measurement takes place is different for the different households. The households were selected in such a way that the pairs were as similar as possible (e.g. age, etc.).
Thus, I have repeated measures for each person (ID) in each household (HOUSEH).
(Unfortunately this is a constructed example similar to my actual experiment, so I cannot share a minimum data example)
As I am primarily interested in the effect of gender and e.g. income one the measured response, I formulated the following model:
lmer(response ~ sex * income + (1|HOUSEH/ID), data = data, REML = FALSE)
With this I account for repeated measurements on persons (IDs) and that each ID belongs to a specific household (HOUSEH). However, this model always throws a warning because of singularity, also if I don't account for any fixed effects. Is there a problem with the forumlation of the random effects or may this simply be due to the fact that there is little within-ID variability? I would highly appreciate any insights.

You don't need the ID grouping level. Household and sex uniquely identify the persons. However, I would specify a random slope too: (sex | HOUSEH)

That actually makes sense, thank you!! But if I don't include any fixed effects and the model is still singular, is it due to the low variance in ID:HOUSEH? I will check the random slope model as well
